# Segmentation Fault on MySQL2 / Ruby 1.9.3 / Rails 3.2

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

I've been having a hard time getting rails 3.2 to work with mysql2.
I'm running OSX 10.6, MySQL 5.1.37

I'm getting this lovely stack trace.

```
HunterMBP:v hunter$ bundle exec rake db:create
/Users/hunter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/mysql2-0.3.2/lib/mysql2/mysql2.bundle: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16 revision 34643) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0033 p:-543968548 s:0099 b:0099 l:000098 d:000098 TOP   
c:0032 p:---- s:0097 b:0097 l:000096 d:000096 CFUNC  :require
c:0031 p:0107 s:0093 b:0093 l:000092 d:000092 TOP    /Users/hunter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/mysql2-0.3.2/lib/mysql2.rb:8
c:0030 p:---- s:0091 b:0091 l:000090 d:000090 FINISH
c:0029 p:---- s:0089 b:0089 l:000088 d:000088 CFUNC  :require
c:0028 p:0026 s:0085 b:0085 l:000065 d:000084 BLOCK  /Users/hunter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/bundler-1.1.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68
c:0027 p:---- s:0082 b:0082 l:000081 d:000081 FINISH
c:0026 p:---- s:0080 b:0080 l:000079 d:000079 CFUNC  :each
c:0025 p:0091 s:0077 b:0077 l:000065 d:000076 BLOCK  /Users/hunter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/bundler-1.1.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66
c:0024 p:---- s:0071 b:0071 l:000070 d:000070 FINISH
c:0023 p:---- s:0069 b:0069 l:000068 d:000068 CFUNC  :each
c:0022 p:0046 s:0066 b:0066 l:000065 d:000065 METHOD /Users/hunter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/bundler-1.1.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55
c:0021 p:0021 s:0062 b:0062 l:000061 d:000061 METHOD /Users/hunter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/bundler-1.1.0/lib/bundler.rb:118
c:0020 p:0137 s:0058 b:0058 l:000057 d:000057 TOP    /Users/hunter/Workspace/Projects/Visionare/config/application.rb:13
c:0019 p:---- s:0056 b:0056 l:000055 d:000055 FINISH
c:0018 p:---- s:0054 b:0054 l:000053 d:000053 CFUNC  :require
c:0017 p:0026 s:0050 b:0050 l:000049 d:000049 TOP    /Users/hunter/Workspace/Projects/Visionare/Rakefile:5
c:0016 p:---- s:0048 b:0048 l:000047 d:000047 FINISH
c:0015 p:---- s:0046 b:0046 l:000045 d:000045 CFUNC  :load
c:0014 p:0013 s:0042 b:0042 l:000041 d:000041 METHOD /Users/hunter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25
c:0013 p:0274 s:0038 b:0038 l:000037 d:000037 METHOD /Users/hunter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:501
c:0012 p:0009 s:0033 b:0033 l:000026 d:000032 BLOCK  /Users/hunter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:82
c:0011 p:0009 s:0031 b:0031 l:000030 d:000030 METHOD /Users/hunter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133
c:0010 p:0011 s:0027 b:0027 l:000026 d:000026 METHOD /Users/hunter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:81
c:0009 p:0019 s:0024 b:0024 l:000017 d:000023 BLOCK  /Users/hunter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:65
c:0008 p:0009 s:0022 b:0022 l:000021 d:000021 METHOD /Users/hunter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133
c:0007 p:0011 s:0018 b:0018 l:000017 d:000017 METHOD /Users/hunter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63
c:0006 p:0060 s:0015 b:0015 l:000014 d:000014 TOP    /Users/hunter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33
c:0005 p:---- s:0013 b:0013 l:000012 d:000012 FINISH
c:0004 p:---- s:0011 b:0011 l:000010 d:000010 CFUNC  :load
c:0003 p:0127 s:0007 b:0007 l:002398 d:001e70 EVAL   /Users/hunter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/rake:19
c:0002 p:---- s:0004 b:0004 l:000003 d:000003 FINISH
c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 b:0002 l:002398 d:002398 TOP   

-- Ruby level backtrace information ----------------------------------------
/Users/hunter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
/Users/hunter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/Users/hunter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/hunter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/Users/hunter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/hunter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:65:in `block in run'
/Users/hunter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:81:in `load_rakefile'
/Users/hunter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/hunter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:82:in `block in load_rakefile'
/Users/hunter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:501:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/Users/hunter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
/Users/hunter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
/Users/hunter/Workspace/Projects/Visionare/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/hunter/Workspace/Projects/Visionare/Rakefile:5:in `require'
/Users/hunter/Workspace/Projects/Visionare/config/application.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/hunter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/bundler-1.1.0/lib/bundler.rb:118:in `require'
/Users/hunter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/bundler-1.1.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
/Users/hunter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/bundler-1.1.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
/Users/hunter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/bundler-1.1.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
/Users/hunter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/bundler-1.1.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
/Users/hunter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/bundler-1.1.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/Users/hunter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/bundler-1.1.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
/Users/hunter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/mysql2-0.3.2/lib/mysql2.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/hunter/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/mysql2-0.3.2/lib/mysql2.rb:8:in `require'
```

Gemfile looks like this:

```
    source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '3.2.2'
#gem 'json'
gem "mysql2"
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem "rspec-rails", ">= 2.8.1", :group => [:development, :test]
gem "factory_girl_rails", ">= 1.7.0", :group => :test
gem "email_spec", ">= 1.2.1", :group => :test
gem "cucumber-rails", ">= 1.3.0", :group => :test
gem "capybara", ">= 1.1.2", :group => :test
gem "database_cleaner", ">= 0.7.1", :group => :test
gem "launchy", ">= 2.0.5", :group => :test
gem "devise", ">= 2.0.4"
```

I have rails 3.2 and ruby 1.9.3

bundle install produces this list successfully.

```
Using rake (0.9.2.2) 
Using i18n (0.6.0) 
Using multi_json (1.1.0) 
Using activesupport (3.2.2) 
Using builder (3.0.0) 
Using activemodel (3.2.2) 
Using erubis (2.7.0) 
Using journey (1.0.3) 
Using rack (1.4.1) 
Using rack-cache (1.2) 
Using rack-test (0.6.1) 
Using hike (1.2.1) 
Using tilt (1.3.3) 
Using sprockets (2.1.2) 
Using actionpack (3.2.2) 
Using mime-types (1.17.2) 
Using polyglot (0.3.3) 
Using treetop (1.4.10) 
Using mail (2.4.3) 
Using actionmailer (3.2.2) 
Using arel (3.0.2) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.32) 
Using activerecord (3.2.2) 
Using activeresource (3.2.2) 
Using addressable (2.2.7) 
Using bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1) 
Using nokogiri (1.5.2) 
Using ffi (1.0.11) 
Using childprocess (0.3.1) 
Using rubyzip (0.9.6.1) 
Using selenium-webdriver (2.20.0) 
Using xpath (0.1.4) 
Using capybara (1.1.2) 
Using coffee-script-source (1.2.0) 
Using execjs (1.3.0) 
Using coffee-script (2.2.0) 
Using rack-ssl (1.3.2) 
Using json (1.6.5) 
Using rdoc (3.12) 
Using thor (0.14.6) 
Using railties (3.2.2) 
Using coffee-rails (3.2.2) 
Using diff-lcs (1.1.3) 
Using gherkin (2.9.0) 
Using term-ansicolor (1.0.7) 
Using cucumber (1.1.9) 
Using cucumber-rails (1.3.0) 
Using database_cleaner (0.7.1) 
Using orm_adapter (0.0.6) 
Using warden (1.1.1) 
Using devise (2.0.4) 
Using rspec-core (2.8.0) 
Using rspec-expectations (2.8.0) 
Using rspec-mocks (2.8.0) 
Using rspec (2.8.0) 
Using email_spec (1.2.1) 
Using factory_girl (2.6.3) 
Using factory_girl_rails (1.7.0) 
Using jquery-rails (2.0.1) 
Using launchy (2.0.5) 
Using mysql2 (0.3.2) 
Using bundler (1.1.0) 
Using rails (3.2.2) 
Using rspec-rails (2.8.1) 
Using sass (3.1.15) 
Using sass-rails (3.2.4) 
Using uglifier (1.2.3)
```

Comment: Which XCode version do you have? > 4.1 ? How do you installed mysql?

Comment: I'm not sure, it's on my home laptop and I'm at work right now.  I can tell you that a rails 3.1 project with ruby 1.8.7 and the mysql2 gem worked fine. Also I was reading that the active record support for mysql2 was brought into the native libraries?  How does this impact the use of the mysql2 gem?

Comment: I've not tested it with Snow Leopard, but on Lion there are lots of problem with gems (especially database driver). This is due to the new C compiler introduced with XCode > 4.1. If you have installed mysql server with `homebrew`you can try using [these instructions](http://abisso.org/2012/03/failed-to-allocate-memory/).

Answer (score 3):

```
rvm reset
```

and then running

```
bundle install
```

helped me with this problem :)

Answer (score 1):

I have been running into this error as well and my searches brought up this thread.

In my particular instance I get segmentation faults but only when update statments are issued to the database.

Noting so far turned out to be fixing it and well being an IT guy I only read the manual once me and google cant come up with an answer.

the mysql-2.8.1-x86-mingw32 documentation mentions the following

> Warning about incompatible MySQL versions
>
> Mixing MySQL versions will generate segmentation faults.
>
> Running the binary version of this gem against a different version of
>   MySQL shared library libMySQL.dll will generate segmentation faults
>   and terminate your application.

so looking deeper into that i find "Binary version built against MySQL 5.0.83"
however i am running 5.1.37 -_- so i will ether have to find an updated API or downgrade my mysql database server to see if that fixes the problem.

I have yet to solve the problem but this may or may not be useful to you but as i don't see this mentioned in other articles i thought I should share my "Revelation".

UPDATE:
hmm ok i decided to update the mysql api and they have made some key changes to it now at least its trowing an error at startup if its incompatible.
"Incorrect MySQL client library version! This gem was compiled for 6.0.0 but the client library is 5.1.37. (RuntimeError)"
6.0.0 made me wonder but ok on to the mysql website then, but hey there is no mention of 6.0.0 on the mysql website.

ok my development enviroment got a little outdated but where would i get client version 6 ?
nvm that last question: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/

Anonther UPDATE:
Well looks like thaty fixt it for me at least.
make sure your version of the connector/c matches what the mysql api was build for.
I installed 6.0.0 and no more segmentation faults.
it wasont obvous where you could still get 6.0.0 since the current is 6.0.2 but here is a link http://mirror.services.wisc.edu/mysql/Downloads/Connector-C/
or you instal a matching version of the connector (doesnt have to match your DBserver verion)

Answer (score 0):

I had a lot of segmentation fault errors with Ruby 1.9.3p125, have you tried running that with Ruby 1.9.3p0? I went back to it after having this sort of problems. If p0 works, then raise an issue ticket at the ruby tracker.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
rvm reset
```

I just have a similar bug

Comment: According to the documentation, this resets the default rvm. How does this help? https://rvm.io//rubies/default/

Answer (score 0):

Execute this command before starting ruby:

```
export RUBYOPT="-r openssl"
```

Answer (score 0):

The above error is mainly due to the upgrade of ruby and rails. I faced this when i upgrade my ruby version to 2.0 and rails version to 4.0. The projects which are using the older versions faced this type of problem since those gems are compiled by older version of ruby. It first shows the error for mysql2 and it keep continuing for other gems too. The solution for this is to uninstall the gems that caused error and install it back. By the way, the mismatch in the compiled versions of gem gets rectified and now it will work.

You need to repeat the process for all the gems that cause issue until you are able to run the server.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and a `rbenv rehash` fixed it.