# Ruby 'mysql' gem segmentation fault

Tags: mysql, ruby

I'm using Ruby 1.9.3 and I'm experiencing this strange problem with the 'mysql' Ruby gem going on segmentation fault exactly after the execution of 20 queries.

This is the code which executes the query:

```
def load
        dbh = Mysql::new($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME)
        begin
            res = dbh.query("SELECT word, type FROM words WHERE word = '#{dbh.escape_string(word)}';")
        rescue Mysql::Error => e
            puts "Error occurred during SQL query"
        end
        res.each do |row|
            @word = row[0]
            @type = row[1]
        end
        dbh.close if dbh
    end
```

This code gets called everytime the user enters a word, for the first 20 words the query works right and goes on segfault on the 21st no matter what I put in there.

I'm on Windows, using Ruby 1.9.3p0 and ruby 'mysql' gem version 2.8.1, with MySQL 5.5.16. I've already checked that the libmysql.dll file I copied into the Ruby bin folder is the same version of the MySQL I have installed.

Do you have any other hint about what could be going wrong?

Comment: Did you search SO for a previously asked question? Could have sworn I seen an exact match earlier this week.

Comment: @MikePurcell: I think you're referring to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9667091/segmentation-fault-on-mysql2-ruby-1-9-3-rails-3-2 but the question has no answers yet and the OS is different so I think even the situation could be different. I've also read other ones but there's no useful info on how to solve this aside from what I've already tried unsuccessfully.

Comment: Can you try this using the 'mysql2' gem instead of 'mysql' gem?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution for anyone who comes across this in the future:

> It seems the reason is that this version of mysql gem does not work
>   with MySQL 5.1 lib. [...] Download MySQL 5.0 noinstall
>   version mysql-noinstall-5.0.89-win32.zip from
>   http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.0.html. Extract libmysql.dll
>   and copy it to C:\Ruby\bin. Then, the problem is solved. I am still
>   running MySQL 5.1. But Ruby uses this MySQL 5.0 version dll.

Source: http://fuyun.org/2010/01/ruby-mysql-adapter-on-windows/